# Printing a Message Entered By User Multiple Times (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am testing a feature to use it in a bigger project in Android Studio.

I need the code to capture the text length entered by user and print that text number of times equal to the length of the entered text using For loop. For example, if the user wrote **car** i need the code to print **car** 3 times (same as the length of the text).

The below code currently prints the text only one time.

Appreciate your kind support 
Below you can find my .java and .xml codes

.java:

```
package com.app.lenovo.firstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView MyText = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        for (int i = message.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            MyText.setText(message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.lenovo.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `MyText.setText(message + "\n");` in your for, you erase the previous text. You have to append it instead.

It would work if you use it like this:

```
 String text = "";
 for (int i = message.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        text += (message + "\n");
 }
 MyText.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to print out the message to the length of text inputted by user, append the text each time as you are overwriting everytime.